# cookieContainer with Typed Clients

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, cookiecontainer, httpclientfactory

Need to make a request to server which need specific cookies. Able to do this using HTTP client and handler with cookiecontainer. By using Typed clients, not able to find a way to set cookiecontainer.

Using httpclient:

```
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    //.....

    // Used below method to add cookies
    AddCookies(cookieContainer);

    var response = client.GetAsync('/').Result;
}
```

Using HttpClientFactory:

In startup.cs

```
services.AddHttpClient<TypedClient>().
           ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
           {
               CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
            });
```

In controller class

```
// Need to call AddCookie method here
var response =_typedclient.client.GetAsync('/').Result;
```

In Addcookie method, I need to add cookies to container. Any suggestions how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an abstraction to provide access to an instance of `CookieContainer`

For example

```
public interface ICookieContainerAccessor {
    CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; }
}

public class DefaultCookieContainerAccessor : ICookieContainerAccessor {
    private static Lazy<CookieContainer> container = new Lazy<CookieContainer>();
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer => container.Value;
}
```

Add cookie container to service collection during startup and use it to configure primary HTTP message handler

*Startup.ConfigureServices*

```
//create cookie container separately            
//and register it as a singleton to be accesed later
services.AddSingleton<ICookieContainerAccessor, DefaultCookieContainerAccessor>();

services.AddHttpClient<TypedClient>()
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(sp =>
        new HttpClientHandler {
            //pass the container to the handler
            CookieContainer = sp.GetRequiredService<ICookieContainerAccessor>().CookieContainer
        }
    );
```

And lastly, inject abstraction where needed

For example

```
public class MyClass{
    private readonly ICookieContainerAccessor accessor;
    private readonly TypedClient typedClient;

    public MyClass(TypedClient typedClient, ICookieContainerAccessor accessor) {
        this.accessor = accessor;
        this.typedClient = typedClient;
    }

    public async Task SomeMethodAsync() {
        // Need to call AddCookie method here           
        var cookieContainer = accessor.CookieContainer;
        AddCookies(cookieContainer);

        var response = await typedclient.client.GetAsync('/');

        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to clear cookies of previous request or get new CookieContainer for each request ?